# Org-Mode Archiving: Create containing headings

Tags: org-mode

I've started using org-mode and am now at the point where I really need archiving. However, I often have sub-projects which are hard to understand without the containing project (i.e., the ancestors in the tree).

Is it possible to archive a subtree while creating the super-tree (if it does not exist yet)?

Concrete example. Say my `gtd.org` file looks like this:

```
* Private
** TODO Organize all my Todos
[…] 

* Work
[…]
** TODO Awesome Project
*** DONE Organize all my Todos
**** DONE Do X
**** DONE Do Y
*** TODO Get Work Done
```

And my `gtd.org_archive` file is empty. Now, when I archive the "DONE Organize all my Todos" task, this is what I want my archive file to look like:

```
* Work
** Awesome Project
*** DONE Organize all my Todos
**** DONE Do X
**** DONE Do Y
```

Obviously, when later archiving other stuff, it should figure out whether the containing tree must be created or is already there. E.g., if I later set the "Get Work Done" to DONE and archive it, this is how the archive should look like:

```
* Work
** Awesome Project
*** DONE Organize all my Todos
**** DONE Do X
**** DONE Do Y
*** DONE Get Work Done
```

It should not create a new `* Work / ** Awesome Project` tree. However, when I later archive the "Organize all my Todos" under "Private", it should not be mixed up with the one under work, but look like this:

```
* Private
** DONE Organize all my Todos

* Work
** Awesome Project
*** DONE Organize all my Todos
**** DONE Do X
**** DONE Do Y
*** DONE Get Work Done
```

Is there any way of achieving this using org-mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the org mode FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#orgdd31094) is a link to [code from edgimar](https://gist.github.com/edgimar/072d99d8650abe81a9fe7c8687c0c993) which should be able to preserve the structure.

I'm unsure if I should insert the code here or if it's too long for that. I'll open this answer as wiki in case someone else wants to decide.

Comment: Can't find the Wiki checkbox in the app, will change from home.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much what I was looking for! However, for some reason the save-buffer command in line 115 seems not to work - emacs keeps asking me whether I really want to kill the unsaved buffer. I removed the kill-buffer and save the buffer manually now. However, I still wonder why save-buffer seems to be ignored…

Comment: Oh, that's probably because save-buffer always saves the current buffer. That worked for edgimar, because he archived in the same file, but I use a separate archive file… I guess it should be something along the lines of:       (when (not (eq source-buffer target-buffer))
    (with-current-buffer target-buffer
     (save-buffer)
     )
   )